# gitolite not working with sshd service

Tags: ssh, gitolite

I'm trying to get gitolite to work and have been stuck for hours. CentOS 6 server on my LAN.

I finally got `ssh -vvv gitolite` to work with this config file

```
Host gitolite
 User gitolite
 HostName srv
 Port 2002
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/srv_gitolite_openssh
```

**BUT** it only works when I do this on the server to debug

```
sudo service sshd stop
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -Dd
```

When sshd is running as a service, the connection fails.

http://pastebin.com/UHVS1sSK

Why does it work when I manually run sshd, but not with sshd as a service? It seems to use the same `sshd_config` file, because it uses the same port number. Also, my username `gitolite` is in the `AllowUsers` part of the config.

The success case looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/x4TcrG4R

**Update**: Here are the server-side logs

fail as a service: http://pastebin.com/Xce2k2x5

success: http://pastebin.com/jYgiDhEm

highlights from the fail case are below. Shouldn't the "key_from_blob" be the same in both cases? I've tried removing the command part of the authorized_keys and it still fails as a service.

```
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 0x7f72b6e93350
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 505/505 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /var/lib/gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 505/505 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /var/lib/gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys2
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for gitolite from 192.168.1.201 port 57488 ssh2
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x7f72b6e93350 is not allowed
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 22
```

highlights from the success case:

```
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 0x7f4d79de18b0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 505/505 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /var/lib/gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug3: secure_filename: checking '/var/lib/gitolite/.ssh'
debug3: secure_filename: checking '/var/lib/gitolite'
debug3: secure_filename: terminating check at '/var/lib/gitolite'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'command="/var/lib/gitolite/bin/gitolite-shell'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug2: user_key_allowed: check options: 'command="/var/lib/gitolite/bin/gitolite-shell gitolite",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIBrEOo5blAUXXSwXdxUxTOhBDHcjw2OzxGg6Vu4drzmUYL5uPxjWLGzuzcNkrYmlVqXr5UBqeSbkZh9W/0lLMcmiv5FLdIQ+J2m5lqHsEJLS8FImfJxfo2/LvboFy0NFOxF8GaHxeIWFp+YmwAlogO9gi1zgXK99DGc15W/edYwCw==
'
debug1: matching key found: file /var/lib/gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 2
Found matching RSA key: ae:92:1d:a7:7b:ec:75:7a:19:ac:28:75:b0:cc:27:8f
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x7f4d79de18b0 is allowed
```

Comment: SELinux was the case, `restorecon -r -vv /var/lib/gitolite/.ssh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the keys are working in both cases.

But running `sshd` as a service is different than running it from the current session: see "[Why would I use “`service sshd reload`” in preference to “`service sshd restart`”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591458/why-would-i-use-service-sshd-reload-in-preference-to-service-sshd-restart)".

The service cancels all inherited environment variables, and keep only `PATH` and `TERM`.

[Gitolite uses a forced command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309) registered in `~gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and there must be an environment variable missing (when sshd is run as a service) which prevents the execution of the command.

---

There was a similar case with "[public key authentication fails ONLY when sshd is daemon](https://serverfault.com/a/321568/783)":

> SELinux is likely the cause.
>   The `.ssh` dir is probably mislabeled.
>
> Look at `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. It should be labeled `ssh_home_t`.
>   Check with `ls -laZ. Run restorecon -r -vv /root/.ssh` if need be.

Comment: Thanks for those hints as to what may be different. Are there any logs I can look at to get more hints? I think I have a pretty standard init.d/sshd (I haven't changed anything), so I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: @Matt it wouldn't work because of the difference in the environment variables (the `env -i` part). As for the logs, they generally are in /var/log/syslog or other `/var/log/*`. Do a `find /var -mmin -60 -print` to see what files have changed recently.

Comment: I'm not sure if the forced command is the issue here, seems like the key isn't being accepted in the case where it is a service. See my update.

Comment: @Matt Can you check your `/var/log/audit/audit.log`? See my edited answer.